# How do I subscribe dict object from ROS?

Tags: python, ros, subscriber

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     rospy.init_node('grounding_node_temp')
     rospy.sleep(1.0)
     pub = rospy.Publisher('/task_commands', String, queue_size=10, latch=True)
     rospy.sleep(1.0)


     d = {"storage_left": ['book', 'eraser', 'soap2'], "storage_right": ['snacks', 'biscuits', 'glue', 'soap'] }

     pub.publish(json.dumps(d, encoding='ascii'))
     rospy.sleep(1.0)
     rospy.spin()
```

How can I subscribe this dict object information?
Or it will be better if I can use this information at other code so that I can obtain the list of objects.
For typical example like talker.py and listener.py, there is `rospy.loginfo()` in `talker.py` and `listener.py` has callback function with `rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() .... )`. And `rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id())` subscribes the information from `talker.py`. Just like this, I want to get information from above dict object but I don't know how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this, for example I have my_script.py with the following code

```
my_dict = {
    'id': 1
}
```

you can access the dict using `import` statement

```
import my_script

print(my_script.my_dict) # { 'id': 1 }
```

Comment: I did similarly but it says 'AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'my_dict' ' (for my case, 'd').

Comment: you need to put them under the same directory, if not you need to include the parent directory
```import <parent-directory>.my_script```